# Add certain values from one JSON object to another

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to awkwardly add certain values from a JSON object to a new JSON object. Because the current geocoder i'm using doesn't seem to provide valid geoJSON back to use in the maps load function. So can i add permitted values, to the new object so it can be queried?

I have a return result of geoCoder which i strip the values using

```js
var businessLoc = JSON.stringify(business1);

permittedValues = [].concat(
  ...business1.map(v => [
    "type:" + v.type + ",",
    "geometry{" + v.geometry + "}"
  ])
);

console.log(permittedValues);

var newObj = {
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features: [{

  }]
};

var jsonObj = {};

features = newObj.features.geometry;

for (i = 0; i < permittedValues.length; i++) {
  newObj.features[i] = permittedValues[i];
}

console.log(newObj);

map.addSource("sample", {
  type: "geojson",
  data: newObj
});
```

result

```
0: "type:Feature,"
1: "geometry{[object Object]}"
2: "type:Feature,"
3: "geometry{[object Object]}"
4: "type:Feature,"
5: "geometry{[object Object]}"
6: "type:Feature,"
7: "geometry{[object Object]}"
8: "type:Feature,"
9: "geometry{[object Object]}"
10: "type:Feature,"
11: "geometry{[object Object]}"
12: "type:Feature,"
13: "geometry{[object Object]}"
```

what i want

```
  {
    "type": "FeatureCollection",
    "features": [
      {
        "type": "Feature",
        "geometry": {
          "type": "Point",
          "coordinates": [
            -77.034084142948,
            38.909671288923
          ]
        },
```

Business object

```
[
    {
        "id": "place.5130493894212350",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "place"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.5,
        "properties": {
            "wikidata": "Q1707"
        },
        "text": "Kiel",
        "place_name": "Kiel, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany",
        "bbox": [
            10.033079,
            54.250613,
            10.218225,
            54.43281
        ],
        "center": [
            10.14056,
            54.32528
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                10.14056,
                54.32528
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "region.3063011031043490",
                "short_code": "DE-SH",
                "wikidata": "Q1194",
                "text": "Schleswig-Holstein"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.10743216036480410",
                "short_code": "de",
                "wikidata": "Q183",
                "text": "Germany"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "address.8335542519828468",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "address"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.99,
        "properties": {
            "accuracy": "street"
        },
        "text": "University Roundabout",
        "place_name": "University Roundabout, Bournemouth, Bournemouth, BH12 5EQ, United Kingdom",
        "center": [
            -1.898631,
            50.744119
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -1.898631,
                50.744119
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "postcode.17127909006362680",
                "text": "BH12 5EQ"
            },
            {
                "id": "locality.9889701754251510",
                "wikidata": "Q170478",
                "text": "Bournemouth"
            },
            {
                "id": "place.6137039763504313",
                "wikidata": "Q170478",
                "text": "Bournemouth"
            },
            {
                "id": "district.18683624152369430",
                "wikidata": "Q203349",
                "text": "Poole"
            },
            {
                "id": "region.11773787231453920",
                "short_code": "GB-ENG",
                "wikidata": "Q21",
                "text": "England"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.8605848117814600",
                "short_code": "gb",
                "wikidata": "Q145",
                "text": "United Kingdom"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "address.8335542519828468",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "address"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.99,
        "properties": {
            "accuracy": "street"
        },
        "text": "University Roundabout",
        "place_name": "University Roundabout, Bournemouth, Bournemouth, BH12 5EQ, United Kingdom",
        "center": [
            -1.898631,
            50.744119
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -1.898631,
                50.744119
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "postcode.17127909006362680",
                "text": "BH12 5EQ"
            },
            {
                "id": "locality.9889701754251510",
                "wikidata": "Q170478",
                "text": "Bournemouth"
            },
            {
                "id": "place.6137039763504313",
                "wikidata": "Q170478",
                "text": "Bournemouth"
            },
            {
                "id": "district.18683624152369430",
                "wikidata": "Q203349",
                "text": "Poole"
            },
            {
                "id": "region.11773787231453920",
                "short_code": "GB-ENG",
                "wikidata": "Q21",
                "text": "England"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.8605848117814600",
                "short_code": "gb",
                "wikidata": "Q145",
                "text": "United Kingdom"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "postcode.13814443524261080",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "postcode"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.5,
        "properties": {},
        "text": "PH1 1RX",
        "place_name": "PH1 1RX, Perth, Perth And Kinross, Scotland, United Kingdom",
        "center": [
            -3.48232183369072,
            56.3888139521762
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -3.48232183369072,
                56.3888139521762
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "place.8737048398313509",
                "wikidata": "Q203000",
                "text": "Perth"
            },
            {
                "id": "district.15421108926775810",
                "wikidata": "Q207679",
                "text": "Perth And Kinross"
            },
            {
                "id": "region.7992878537156640",
                "short_code": "GB-SCT",
                "wikidata": "Q22",
                "text": "Scotland"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.8605848117814600",
                "short_code": "gb",
                "wikidata": "Q145",
                "text": "United Kingdom"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "place.10346294296913350",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "place"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.25,
        "properties": {
            "wikidata": "Q1496283"
        },
        "text": "Moreno",
        "place_name": "Moreno, Buenos Aires, Argentina",
        "bbox": [
            -58.890257,
            -34.686207,
            -58.713205,
            -34.508089
        ],
        "center": [
            -58.78724,
            -34.65762
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -58.78724,
                -34.65762
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "region.15410301253886620",
                "short_code": "AR-B",
                "wikidata": "Q44754",
                "text": "Buenos Aires"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.10192800254801190",
                "short_code": "ar",
                "wikidata": "Q414",
                "text": "Argentina"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "place.10346294296913350",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "place"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.25,
        "properties": {
            "wikidata": "Q1496283"
        },
        "text": "Moreno",
        "place_name": "Moreno, Buenos Aires, Argentina",
        "bbox": [
            -58.890257,
            -34.686207,
            -58.713205,
            -34.508089
        ],
        "center": [
            -58.78724,
            -34.65762
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -58.78724,
                -34.65762
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "region.15410301253886620",
                "short_code": "AR-B",
                "wikidata": "Q44754",
                "text": "Buenos Aires"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.10192800254801190",
                "short_code": "ar",
                "wikidata": "Q414",
                "text": "Argentina"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "address.4377709491448262",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "address"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.3205128205128205,
        "properties": {
            "accuracy": "street"
        },
        "text": "Fr Access",
        "place_name": "Fr Access, Lubbock, Texas 79413, United States",
        "matching_text": "University Off",
        "matching_place_name": "University Off, Lubbock, Texas 79413, United States",
        "center": [
            -101.870484,
            33.541972
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -101.870484,
                33.541972
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "neighborhood.2103733",
                "text": "Caprock"
            },
            {
                "id": "postcode.11511121744851560",
                "text": "79413"
            },
            {
                "id": "place.2344342379218940",
                "wikidata": "Q49273",
                "text": "Lubbock"
            },
            {
                "id": "region.5362387429342410",
                "short_code": "US-TX",
                "wikidata": "Q1439",
                "text": "Texas"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                "short_code": "us",
                "wikidata": "Q30",
                "text": "United States"
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

what's close to working

```
permittedValues = [].concat(...business1.map((v) => [v.geometry]))



var newObj = {
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features:[{
    type:'Feature',
    geometry:permittedValues[0]
  }]
};
```

Comment: `newObj.features.append(...)`

Comment: What is `business1`?

Comment: I don't see how the objects you're adding to `newObj` are related to what's in `permittedValues`.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, i've updated my OP to show what i'm doing. So i've kinda got it okay, i was just supplying v.geometry, and that was a valid geojson type. However none of the objects were appearing map. SO i've thought that you need to also supply the type-hence my current train of thought. As you can see however, it's supplying each bit as a seperate result, and the geometry is coming up now as an object

Comment: `v.geometry` is an object. When you write `'geometry{' + v.geometry + '}'` it gets converted to a string so it can be concatenated, and converting an object to a string results in `'[object Object]`. It's not clear what you really want there.

Comment: The `for` loop is just the same as `newObj.features = permittedValues.slice()`.

Comment: I've updated my OP with what i'm aiming for. I want to extract the geometry value (v.geometry), and add this with all the text i need i need to make a valid geojson object.

Comment: You haven't shown the input data, how are we supposed to know how to get that result from it? You had that in the original post, but you removed it when editing.

Comment: Sorry, it's been an interesting day personally so i'm failing at everything. I've updated my OP with the first element of business1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't use string concatenation when creating `permittedValues`, just extract the properties that you want.

```
var permittedValues = business1.map(({type, geometry}) => ({type, geometry}));
var newObj = {
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features: permittedValues
};
```

```js
var business1 = [
    {
        "id": "place.5130493894212350",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "place"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.5,
        "properties": {
            "wikidata": "Q1707"
        },
        "text": "Kiel",
        "place_name": "Kiel, Schleswig-Holstein, Germany",
        "bbox": [
            10.033079,
            54.250613,
            10.218225,
            54.43281
        ],
        "center": [
            10.14056,
            54.32528
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                10.14056,
                54.32528
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "region.3063011031043490",
                "short_code": "DE-SH",
                "wikidata": "Q1194",
                "text": "Schleswig-Holstein"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.10743216036480410",
                "short_code": "de",
                "wikidata": "Q183",
                "text": "Germany"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "address.8335542519828468",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "address"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.99,
        "properties": {
            "accuracy": "street"
        },
        "text": "University Roundabout",
        "place_name": "University Roundabout, Bournemouth, Bournemouth, BH12 5EQ, United Kingdom",
        "center": [
            -1.898631,
            50.744119
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -1.898631,
                50.744119
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "postcode.17127909006362680",
                "text": "BH12 5EQ"
            },
            {
                "id": "locality.9889701754251510",
                "wikidata": "Q170478",
                "text": "Bournemouth"
            },
            {
                "id": "place.6137039763504313",
                "wikidata": "Q170478",
                "text": "Bournemouth"
            },
            {
                "id": "district.18683624152369430",
                "wikidata": "Q203349",
                "text": "Poole"
            },
            {
                "id": "region.11773787231453920",
                "short_code": "GB-ENG",
                "wikidata": "Q21",
                "text": "England"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.8605848117814600",
                "short_code": "gb",
                "wikidata": "Q145",
                "text": "United Kingdom"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "address.8335542519828468",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "address"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.99,
        "properties": {
            "accuracy": "street"
        },
        "text": "University Roundabout",
        "place_name": "University Roundabout, Bournemouth, Bournemouth, BH12 5EQ, United Kingdom",
        "center": [
            -1.898631,
            50.744119
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -1.898631,
                50.744119
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "postcode.17127909006362680",
                "text": "BH12 5EQ"
            },
            {
                "id": "locality.9889701754251510",
                "wikidata": "Q170478",
                "text": "Bournemouth"
            },
            {
                "id": "place.6137039763504313",
                "wikidata": "Q170478",
                "text": "Bournemouth"
            },
            {
                "id": "district.18683624152369430",
                "wikidata": "Q203349",
                "text": "Poole"
            },
            {
                "id": "region.11773787231453920",
                "short_code": "GB-ENG",
                "wikidata": "Q21",
                "text": "England"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.8605848117814600",
                "short_code": "gb",
                "wikidata": "Q145",
                "text": "United Kingdom"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "postcode.13814443524261080",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "postcode"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.5,
        "properties": {},
        "text": "PH1 1RX",
        "place_name": "PH1 1RX, Perth, Perth And Kinross, Scotland, United Kingdom",
        "center": [
            -3.48232183369072,
            56.3888139521762
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -3.48232183369072,
                56.3888139521762
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "place.8737048398313509",
                "wikidata": "Q203000",
                "text": "Perth"
            },
            {
                "id": "district.15421108926775810",
                "wikidata": "Q207679",
                "text": "Perth And Kinross"
            },
            {
                "id": "region.7992878537156640",
                "short_code": "GB-SCT",
                "wikidata": "Q22",
                "text": "Scotland"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.8605848117814600",
                "short_code": "gb",
                "wikidata": "Q145",
                "text": "United Kingdom"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "place.10346294296913350",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "place"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.25,
        "properties": {
            "wikidata": "Q1496283"
        },
        "text": "Moreno",
        "place_name": "Moreno, Buenos Aires, Argentina",
        "bbox": [
            -58.890257,
            -34.686207,
            -58.713205,
            -34.508089
        ],
        "center": [
            -58.78724,
            -34.65762
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -58.78724,
                -34.65762
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "region.15410301253886620",
                "short_code": "AR-B",
                "wikidata": "Q44754",
                "text": "Buenos Aires"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.10192800254801190",
                "short_code": "ar",
                "wikidata": "Q414",
                "text": "Argentina"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "place.10346294296913350",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "place"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.25,
        "properties": {
            "wikidata": "Q1496283"
        },
        "text": "Moreno",
        "place_name": "Moreno, Buenos Aires, Argentina",
        "bbox": [
            -58.890257,
            -34.686207,
            -58.713205,
            -34.508089
        ],
        "center": [
            -58.78724,
            -34.65762
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -58.78724,
                -34.65762
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "region.15410301253886620",
                "short_code": "AR-B",
                "wikidata": "Q44754",
                "text": "Buenos Aires"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.10192800254801190",
                "short_code": "ar",
                "wikidata": "Q414",
                "text": "Argentina"
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "address.4377709491448262",
        "type": "Feature",
        "place_type": [
            "address"
        ],
        "relevance": 0.3205128205128205,
        "properties": {
            "accuracy": "street"
        },
        "text": "Fr Access",
        "place_name": "Fr Access, Lubbock, Texas 79413, United States",
        "matching_text": "University Off",
        "matching_place_name": "University Off, Lubbock, Texas 79413, United States",
        "center": [
            -101.870484,
            33.541972
        ],
        "geometry": {
            "type": "Point",
            "coordinates": [
                -101.870484,
                33.541972
            ]
        },
        "context": [
            {
                "id": "neighborhood.2103733",
                "text": "Caprock"
            },
            {
                "id": "postcode.11511121744851560",
                "text": "79413"
            },
            {
                "id": "place.2344342379218940",
                "wikidata": "Q49273",
                "text": "Lubbock"
            },
            {
                "id": "region.5362387429342410",
                "short_code": "US-TX",
                "wikidata": "Q1439",
                "text": "Texas"
            },
            {
                "id": "country.9053006287256050",
                "short_code": "us",
                "wikidata": "Q30",
                "text": "United States"
            }
        ]
    }
];

var permittedValues = business1.map(({type, geometry}) => ({type, geometry}));
var newObj = {
  type: "FeatureCollection",
  features: permittedValues
};

console.log(newObj);
```

Comment: Really thanks for the answer. Means a lot man.I'm getting this error on your code "Invalid destructuring assignment target". I've been working away on my code (which i've updated in my OP) i can get symbols to now show but only for one location. My problem is The newObj get's overwritten by the last assignment, so i only ever can have one object showing.

Comment: Forgot the arrow, try it now.

Comment: You changed the question again! Now my answer that says not to do string concatenation makes no sense.

Comment: I'll change it back, and then accept your answer to match the question you answered.

Comment: Unfortunately permittedValues returns undefined at the moment with your code.

Comment: Can you post the value of `businessLoc` so I can try with real data?

Comment: I can't figure it out from what you put at the bottom of the question, it's impossible to see how things are nested.

Comment: I've posted what i get back from geocoding

Comment: I needed to wrap the object in parentheses in the arrow function, it was treating the braces as meaning a code block.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/189033/discussion-between-john-doi2021-and-barmar).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the output labeled 'result' is what you get back, have you tried accessing `geometry[0]`? What you are trying to do seems like a lot of effort. Is there no getter, or a method in the API / response to access this data?